# Struct array not allowing push

Tags: arrays, struct, solidity

I am still new to solidity to I thank you to whoever answers this probably simple question.
When learning about function storage and arrays I produced this code and it works:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory is SimpleStorage {
    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;
    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }
    function sFStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
        SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])).store(_simpleStorageNumber);

    }
    function sfGet(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex) public view returns(uint256){
        return SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])).retrieve();

    }
    struct addrToValue{
        address addr;
        uint256 value;
    }
    addrToValue[]  addressesArray;    

    function printAddresses() public returns(addrToValue[] memory){
        for(uint256 _ssArrIndex=0; _ssArrIndex<simpleStorageArray.length; _ssArrIndex++){
            addrToValue memory addressTov;
            addressTov.addr = address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex]);
            addressTov.value = SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex])).retrieve();
            addressesArray.push(addressTov);
            // addressesArray.push(addrToValue( address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex]), SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex])).retrieve()));
        }
        return addressesArray;
    }
}
```

except I keep updating addressesArray, so I tried changing printAddresses to this:

```
  function printAddresses() public returns(addrToValue[] memory){
        addrToValue[]  memory addressesArray;    

        for(uint256 _ssArrIndex=0; _ssArrIndex<simpleStorageArray.length; _ssArrIndex++){
            addrToValue memory addressTov;
            addressTov.addr = address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex]);
            addressTov.value = SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex])).retrieve();
            addressesArray.push(addressTov);
            // addressesArray.push(addrToValue( address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex]), SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex])).retrieve()));
        }
        return addressesArray;
    }
```

but I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: Member "push" is not available in struct StorageFactory.addrToValue memory[] memory outside of storage.
            addressesArray.push(addressTov);
```

I don't understand why it isn't reading my array as an array anymore but just as a struct

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to resize memory arrays (e.g. the .push member functions are not available). You need to know the size of the array beforehand and then write the values.

```
  function printAddresses() public returns(addrToValue[] memory){
        addrToValue[] memory addressesArray = new addrToValue[](simpleStorageArray.length);    
        for(uint256 _ssArrIndex=0; _ssArrIndex<simpleStorageArray.length; _ssArrIndex++){
            addrToValue memory addressTov;
            addressTov.addr = address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex]);
            addressTov.value = SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_ssArrIndex])).retrieve();
            addressesArray[_ssArrIndex] = addressTov;
        }
        return addressesArray;
    }
```